# How to connect ROS(Ubuntu) with Unreal Engine(Windows)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

we implemented a ROS node which publishes messages(velocity, steering angle, ect.). We would like to subscribe this node in windows, so we can can use this data for our car in our unreal engine.

We tried it already with the Tutorial: wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows/Tutorials/Hello World
but we couldnt receive any messages.

Greetings and thanks for your help.

Jürgatt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277092/how-to-connect-ros(ubuntu)-with-unreal-engine(windows)/) by [Jürgatt](https://answers.ros.org/users/32833/j%C3%BCrgatt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You could use this plugin with Unreal to communicate with ROS :
https://github.com/Camille78/Unreal-ros-plugin

However, I can't certify this answer is valid since I haven't tested this plugin.

---

Originally posted by [simchanu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28658/simchanu/) with karma: 20 on 2019-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0